# HTML Search Engine

Tags: html, search-engine

I'm trying to make a simple search engine in html, but I dont know how to take the users input and use it for searching purposes. What I'm trying to achieve is to take the input, and be able to search Google for what was imputed. Can someone help me?

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build search engines.

You can't do that in HTML, as it's a markup language. It isn't a programming language, because it can't use variables, nor do conditional if/else-if/else, nor switch/case logic, nor use loops/repeaters. A search engine has to be written in a programming language, like: JavaScript, PHP, C/C++, C#, Java, etc...

If you're trying to take an input form field in HTML & use it to search Google, where you want to dump the results into either an HTML IFrame or a DIV, then you'll need to use JavaScript. With JS, you can grab the form field... then simply drop it into an iframe or you can make an Ajax call to query Google & then append the results into a div.

I recommend learning JavaScript first, as it's a client-side language. Then learning a back-end language, like the ones listed above. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you cannot do it with only HTML because HTML is an tool. You need programming language to connect with HTML. You have several back end options like Php, Javascript (Node.js), Python (Flask or Django) etc. 
You can search for tutorials for specifed backend programming language and connect it.

IDEA: To send user input to the Google search you might want to search for an Google search API